# variable to hold multiple selectors

Tags: jquery, variables

I have a lot of selectors which I need to manipulate several times in a script.

So far I have done this:

```
var allSelectors3 = $('#icon20,#icon21,#icon22,#icon23,#icon24,#icon25,#icon26,#icon27,#icon28,#icon29,#icon30,#icon31,#icon32');
var allSelectors2 = $('#icon12,#icon13,#icon14,#icon15,#icon16,#icon17,#icon18,#icon19'); 
var allSelectors = $('#icon2,#icon3,#icon4,#icon5,#icon6,#icon7,#icon8,#icon9,#icon10,#icon11');

$(allSelectors).show();
$(allSelectors2, allSelectors3).hide();
```

Is this the best way to do this?

Comment: I think it would be better using classes in html, the selectors would be a lot simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no need for the second `$()`.

```
var allSelectors = $('#icon20,#icon21,#icon22,#icon23,#icon24,#icon25,#icon26,#icon27,#icon28,#icon29,#icon30,#icon31,#icon32');
allSelectors.show()
```

to combine 2 lists use `.add`

```
allSelectors2.add(allSelectors3).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since no one has mentioned **jQuery performance rules**, here are the [performance rules](http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/).

Its good to declare selectors in a variable (if you have large number of them), and I see you doing it correctly.

Another option would be add a class to each element you have in Selectors1 as `class="selector1"`, and so on. And then use:

```
$(".Selectors").show();
$(".Selectors2").hide();
$(".Selectors3").hide();
```

This is quite good-looking, but as you read in the performance rules, selction by class and other attributes is slower.

Also **no need for the second $()**. Use this directly:

```
var allSelectors3 = $('#icon20,#icon21,#icon22,#icon23,#icon24,#icon25,#icon26,#icon27,#icon28,#icon29,#icon30,#icon31,#icon32');
var allSelectors2 = $('#icon12,#icon13,#icon14,#icon15,#icon16,#icon17,#icon18,#icon19'); 
var allSelectors = $('#icon2,#icon3,#icon4,#icon5,#icon6,#icon7,#icon8,#icon9,#icon10,#icon11');

allSelectors.show();
allSelectors2.hide();
allSelectors3.hide();
```